# Based vs unbased spectra

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

I am trying to understand the potentially alternative definition of spectra in stable homotopy theory. I am assuming that everything is $\infty$-categorical.

I will focus on finite spectra.
One definition of finite spectra is as the Spanier-Whitehead category: the colimit $\lim_{\rightarrow} (Space^{w}_* \overset{\Sigma^{red}} \rightarrow Space^{w}_* \overset{\Sigma^{red}} \rightarrow \cdots )$, where $Space^{w}_*$ are based spaces that are compact objects (retracts of finite spaces)
and $\Sigma^{red}$ is the reduced suspension. My understanding is that this is a good definition since is equivalent to the limit definition of spectra under the based loop space functor. Also, $Space^{w}_*$ has a zero object and all colimits, so inverting the suspension functor makes finite limits and colimits coincide.

However I was wondering why one cannot take unbased spaces and the ``standard" suspension as the definition of spectra:
$\lim_{\rightarrow} (Space^{w} \overset{\Sigma} \rightarrow Space^{w} \overset{\Sigma} \rightarrow \cdots )$.
Here I am defining $\Sigma X$ as the homotopy pushout of $X$ along the two terminal maps $X\rightarrow *$. So $\Sigma \varnothing \cong * \coprod * \cong S^0$.

It seems like every $\Sigma X$ has a natural basepoint, say given by one of the cone points in $\Sigma X$ (say the left one).
Furthermore, the mapping spaces in these two colimits agree. After suspending, it does not matter whether basepoints are preserved or not. That is, $Map((X,x_0), (Y,y_0))$ and $Map(X, Y)$ are part of a fiber sequence with base $Y$:
$$
Map((X,x_0), (Y,y_0)) \rightarrow Map(X, Y) \overset{ev_{x_0}} \rightarrow Y
$$
and if we suspend $Y$, then in the limit they are equivalent spaces.

**Questions**

a) Why not use unbased spectra, as in the second colimit above?

b) Could it be that the categories of unbased and based finite spectra agree?

Comment: where are the friendly loops

Comment: @AndresMejia maybe I should have said that I'm working with finite spectra where I can use the Spanier-Whitehead category (which is what I started with). Is this what you mean by your comment?

Comment: Are you working with the $\infty$-category of spaces, and generally in the $\infty$-categorical setting?

Comment: For now, I'm working with the $\infty$-category of spaces. I think one could ask these questions about the stabilization of a general $\infty$-category $C$ with finite colimits.

Comment: Maybe it's better to say in the post that everything in sight is $\infty$-categorical: there are many different models and model categories of spectra, and it helps to immediately specify what your setting is. Also, if you would want to go to a general $\infty$-category $\mathscr{C}$, at the very least you want it to be presentable, because otherwise this suspension definition is not the correct one. (But probably we should just focus on spaces for now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be any $\infty$-category with finite colimits and a terminal object $*$. We denote $\mathscr{C}_*=*/\mathscr{C}$. Let $\mathsf{A}$ be the diagram shape $2\leftarrow 0\to 1$, and let $i_0\colon[0]\to\mathsf{A}, 0\mapsto 0$ be the inclusion of the initial vertex, with corresponding right Kan extension $\mathrm{Ran}_{i_0}\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})$ (informally sending $X$ to a diagram $*\leftarrow X\to *$). Let $\mathsf{Sq}$ be the commutative square category
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> 1\\
@VVV @VVV\\
2@>>> 3
\end{CD}
$$
with corresponding inclusion functor $i\colon\mathsf{A}\to\mathsf{Sq}$. This gives us a corresponding left Kan extension $\mathrm{Lan}_{i}\colon\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})\to\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})$, which takes a colimit of the span to ''complete the square''. Let $\mathsf{E}$ be the one-arrow category $1\to 3$, with corresponding inclusion functor $j\colon\mathsf{E}\to\mathsf{Sq}$. We define a functor $\widetilde{\Sigma}_+\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}_*$ as the composite
$$
\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Ran}_{i_0}}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{A},\mathscr{C})\xrightarrow{\mathrm{Lan}_{i}}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Sq},\mathscr{C})\xrightarrow{j^*}\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{E},\mathscr{C})\simeq\mathrm{Ar}(\mathscr{C}),
$$
which lands in the full subcategory of the arrow category $\mathrm{Ar}(\mathscr{C})$ on the arrows with $*$ as domain. Hence $\widetilde{\Sigma}_+$ factors through the inclusion $\mathscr{C}_*\to\mathrm{Ar}(\mathscr{C})$. Denote by $\Sigma_+\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}_*$ the resulting functor. Writing $U\colon\mathscr{C}_*\to\mathscr{C}$ for the forgetful functor, we of course have $\Sigma\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}$ to be naturally equivalent to $U\Sigma_+$. In a similar way, we can formally define the suspension functor $\mathrm{Sigma}_*\colon\mathscr{C}_*\to\mathscr{C}_*$. Given an object $(X,x)$ of $\mathscr{C}_*$, the object $\mathrm{Sigma}_*(X,x)$ is naturally equivalent to $\Sigma X$ equipped with the basepoint $*\xrightarrow{x}X\to\Sigma X$. However, since $X\to\Sigma X$ factors as $X\to *\to \Sigma X$, where $*$ is the terminal object at position $1$ in $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{Sq}$, we find that this basepoint is naturally equivalent to the basepoint that $\Sigma X$ receives from its lift $\Sigma_+X$. In fact, we find that $\Sigma_*(X,x)\simeq\Sigma_+U(X,x)$ naturally in $(X,x)$.

This means that the diagram
[image]
of $\infty$-categories and functors commutes. This in turn implies that
$$
\mathrm{colim}(\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\Sigma}\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\Sigma}\ldots)\simeq\mathrm{colim}(\mathscr{C}_*\xrightarrow{\Sigma_*}\mathscr{C}_*\xrightarrow{\Sigma_*}\ldots),
$$
so the two definitions agree. (Note that, for general $\mathscr{C}$, neither of these $\infty$-categories will model spectrum objects in $\mathscr{C}$.)

That leaves the question why we prefer to work with the pointed version. I can think of a couple of reasons: firstly, pointed categories are easier to work with than unpointed ones. Having a zero map can for instance make it easier to make certain constructions natural. Secondly, the suspension functor $\Sigma$ as defined above is generally not a left adjoint even if $\mathscr{C}$ has finite limits, while $\Sigma_*$ is in that case (from now on, just assume $\mathscr{C}$ has finite limits). $\Sigma_+$ is also not a left adjoint: you really need to choose both natural basepoints of $\Sigma X$ as such and consider the lift $\Sigma_{++}\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}_{*\sqcup*/}$ to get a right adjoint functor, namely the loop functor $\Omega$. But as said, $\Sigma_*$ is just immediately a left adjoint. This is particularly helpful if you don't work $\infty$-categorically: if you work with model categories, then your main way to model $\infty$-functors is by building Quillen adjunctions. In particular, you want a good supply of adjoint $1$-functors, so you prefer to work with the pointed version. But also $\infty$-categorically we prefer adjoint functors over non-adjoint ones. Thirdly, the equivalence
$$
\mathrm{colim}(\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\Sigma}\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\Sigma}\ldots)\xrightarrow{\simeq}\mathrm{colim}(\mathscr{C}_*\xrightarrow{\Sigma_*}\mathscr{C}_*\xrightarrow{\Sigma_*}\ldots),
$$
defined above requires a choice, namely the choice in the definition of $\Sigma_+$ to let one, and not the other natural candidate for the basepoint be the actual basepoint. You might object, and say that if we let $\Sigma_{-}$ denote the functor we would get by choosing the other basepoint, then the fact that both $\Sigma_+$ and $\Sigma_{-}$ induce on colimits inverses to the canonical equivalence
$$
\mathrm{colim}(\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\Sigma}\mathscr{C}\xrightarrow{\Sigma}\ldots)\xleftarrow{\simeq}\mathrm{colim}(\mathscr{C}_*\xrightarrow{\Sigma_*}\mathscr{C}_*\xrightarrow{\Sigma_*}\ldots),
$$
in the other direction (the one induced by $U$) would imply that both $\Sigma_+$ and $\Sigma_{-}$ induce up to equivalence the same map on colimits. And while that is true, it is not up to *canonical* equivalence. So there is a very slight non-canonical thing occurring because we had to choose whether the north or the south pole of our suspension was the base point. And while these can be connected by a path, the choice of path is not canonically determined up to higher homotopies. In the pointed setting, everything is completely canonical. There probably are more reasons (also of less philosophical and more practical nature), but I'll keep it at this for now.